# data link layer programming in c

Tags: c, ubuntu, hardware

I'm totally newbie about this thing and I want to know where to start..
I have a manual that specifies data link layer that includes command and response frames to access a device connected in **/dev/ttyUSB0**.
**Example of the given command frame is setting the baud rate**
**Head** = 0x0A
**Address** = NULL/blank
**Length** =  0x03
**Command** = 0x20
**Parameter** = 0x00
**Check** = cc

Where parameter 0x00 is equal to baud rate 9600bps.
My question is how do I use this in programming? can I use it on C language?
My OS platform is ubuntu 12.04.
Any link or idea would be a great help.

**UPDATE**
This is the command I used in read()

```
    unsigned char rx_buffer[1024];
    size_t RX_buffer_len;
    ssize_t bytes_read;
    int fd;

    RX_buffer_len = sizeof(rx_buffer);
    bytes_read = read (serial, rx_buffer, RX_buffer_len);
```

Comment: This Link may be some help to you  [`How to read/write to tty* device?`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/138342/how-to-read-write-to-tty-device).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'll read it. But if there is more specific tutorial for this. Please let me know

Comment: I learned all I needed from the linux programmers guide. (and sundry man pages)

Comment: @Jasen thanks for the reference I will try to find that guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could start defining the your packet message structure

```
// Enable 1 byte alignment
#pragma pack(1)

typedef struct
{
    uint8_t Head;
    uint8_t Address;
    uint8_t Length;
    uint8_t Command;
    uint8_t Parameter;
    uint8_t Check;
}typ_packet;

// Restore the original alignment
#pragma pack()
```

Then you can access and configure ttyUSB0. A simple example:

```
struct termios2 t;

int serial, baud;

// Open the uart low level device driver and set up all params
serial_fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

if (serial != -1)
{
    baud = 9600;

    if (ioctl(serial, TCGETS2, &t))
    {
        // Fails to read tty pars
        exit(1);
    }

    t.c_cflag &= ~CBAUD;
    t.c_cflag |= BOTHER;
    t.c_cflag |= CSTOPB;
    t.c_ospeed = baud;

    // Noncanonical mode, disable signals, extended
    // input processing, and echoing
    t.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN | ECHO);

    // Disable special handling of CR, NL, and BREAK.
    // No 8th-bit stripping or parity error handling.
    // Disable START/STOP output flow control.
    t.c_iflag &= ~(BRKINT | ICRNL | IGNBRK | IGNCR | INLCR |
                      INPCK | ISTRIP | IXON | PARMRK);

    // Disable all output processing
    t.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

    if (ioctl(serial, TCSETS2, &t))
    {
        // Failed to set serial parameters
        exit(1);
    }
}
else
{
    // Failed to open ttyUSB0
    exit(1);
}
```

Then you can simply read from serial line by

```
res = read (serial_fd, rx_buffer, RX_buffer_len);
```

And write using

```
typ_packet packet;

packet.Head = 0x0A;
packet.Address = 0x00;
packet.Length = 0x03;
packet.Command = 0x20;
packet.Parameter = 0x00;
packet.Check = 0xCC;

write(serial_fd, &packet, 6);
```

Comment: You may have to define the struct as packed, using whatever pragma/whatever is available from your compiler.

Comment: @MartinJames Yes, you right. I think that the best is to use a header file to define all structures of all packets and use pragma pack for the whole file. Anyway in this case the alignment will be used at the end of structure, because of all members are uint8_t.

Comment: packets are likely variable length, strict is unlikely to work. just use array of unsigned char.

Comment: @Jasen I know. This is a simple example. BTW variable length does not means that could not be defined by struct. I usually define all packet structs and then marge all in a union where a DATA_RAW[MAX_LENGTH] is added to access packets as saw data.

Comment: @LPs. Thank you very much. I will try this and give you feedback after

Comment: @LPs yes, that's what I do:)  Pack up the struct in a union with a byte/char array.   Often, there is more than one struct in the union to accommodate different protocol messages.

Comment: @LPs sir I successfully executed the `write()` and it returned a value of `6` but I'm having problem when using the `read()` command. The program just hang when the command is executed. Please see the update above for the command I use. Hope you help me. Thanks

Comment: @sdfsfssfsdf `read` will block if at least 1 data is available to be read.

Comment: @LPs yes sir but I `write()` the command frame (hexadecimal codes) to get the Firmware version which must return a data.. by the way the hexadecimal codes I used is based on windows, is it possible that the codes are not compatible in ubuntu?

Comment: @sdfsfssfsdf In this case your slave device is not answering you. Take notes that I posted an example code where Check `member` is set at `0xCC`. I don't know if it is the correct value. Maybe there are specifications on how to calculate it.